# CSS multi-line ellipsis is not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I've floating DIV on left side and right side ellipse div,
On mouse hover/out on left side div it is collapse/expand, in this case ellipses are not working.

- I'm using two line ellipses
- It is behaving differently based on content and window size

[image: Demo image]

```js
$(function() {

  $(".left-content").mouseover(function() {
    $(".left").width("30%");
  }).mouseout(function() {

    $(".left").width("50%");
  });

})
```

```css
div.left {
  float: left;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.right {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
div.ellipses-twoline {
  border: solid 2px blue;
  width: 178px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <div class="left-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="ellipses-twoline">Located in Palm Springs and Santa Barbara, California, H3K Design specializes in design consultation and project management for house and building</div>

  <div class="ellipses-twoline">
    Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help
  </div>
</div>
```

View on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prasathmani/vkwg6d6r/)

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/prasathmani/vkwg6d6r/

Comment: Well, they're experimental properties and values. Have you checked the webkit bug tracker to see if it's a known problem? If not, why not raise it there?